# Jquery dropdown menu click always open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I created a dropdown menu click, but it have a little weirdness. When I click the button dropdown, the dropdown menu has appear. But when I move my cursor to another (without click the button dropdown again), the dropdown menu dissapear and it has become hoverable dropdown menu not dropdown menu click (Sorry for my bad English)

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I make the dropdown menu click always appear when I click the button dropdown and move the cursor?

(Here is my code)

HTML

```
<aside class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">home</i>Homepage</a></li>
        <li class="button_dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="material-icons">widgets</i>Events Organizer <i class="material-icons multi_menu">keyboard_arrow_right</i></a>
          <ul class="dropdown_menu">
            <li><a href="#">Create Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">List Events</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">people</i>Peserta Events</a></li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
```

CSS

```
aside.sidebar ul li ul.dropdown_menu {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  border-left: 1px solid #2c3e50;
  background-color: #34495e;
}
aside.sidebar ul li ul.dropdown_menu.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #34495e;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

Jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".button_dropdown").click(function () {
          $(".dropdown_menu").toggleClass("active");
        });
      });
```

Comment: Are you using any frameworks, such as Bootstrap?

Comment: I think your menu is still displaying but is out of the right due to `left:100%`.

Comment: You could do the same thing with html and pure css if that is an option for you

Comment: It's because you have the `aside.sidebar ul li ul.dropdown_menu` set to `left:100%`. This is causing the `ul` to be off the screen due to being 100% across the page from the left. Set it to your width of `sidebar` as shown in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would use `hover` rather than `click` for a child menu. Let me know how you go with this. Stays active until clicked out.

```
aside.sidebar ul li ul.dropdown_menu {
  display: none;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  border-left: 1px solid #2c3e50;
  background-color: #34495e;
  left:200px;
  top:0;
}

aside.sidebar ul li ul.dropdown_menu.active {
  display: block !important;
}
```

Working in this snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button_dropdown').click(function() {
    $('.dropdown_menu').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
aside.sidebar ul li ul.dropdown_menu {
  display: none;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  border-left: 1px solid #2c3e50;
  background-color: #34495e;
  left:200px;
  top:0;
}

aside.sidebar ul li ul.dropdown_menu.active {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<aside class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>Homepage</li>
    <li class="button_dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">Events Organizer</a>
      <ul class="dropdown_menu">
        <li>Create Events</li>
        <li>List Events</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Peserta Events</li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without changing your code too much, you can just remove the pointer-events (clicks, etc.) by adding:

`pointer-events:none;` to `aside.sidebar ul li ul.dropdown_menu`

and

`pointer-events:auto;` to `aside.sidebar ul li ul.dropdown_menu.active`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it doesn't work in my case :)

Answer (score 1):

The hoverable dropdown menu is because you have set the opacity property to 0 in your css aside (dropdown_menu). You must change opacity:0 to opacity:1. Here is your code with error:

```
  aside.sidebar ul li ul.dropdown_menu {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  border-left: 1px solid #2c3e50;
  background-color: #34495e;
}
```

Replace by (fixed opacity):

```
 aside.sidebar ul li ul.dropdown_menu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  border-left: 1px solid #2c3e50;
  background-color: #34495e;
}
```